# Does a weapon imbued with Magical Tinkering or an Infusion bypass resistance from non magic weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, artificer, resistance

When I apply Magical Tinkering or an Infusion to a weapon, does the weapon count as magical to bypass resistance to non-magic weapons?

> **Magical Tinkering** At 1st level, you learn how to invest a spark of magic into mundane objects. To use this ability, you must have tinker's tools or other artisan's tools in hand. You then touch a Tiny nonmagical object as an action [...]
>
> **Infusing an Item** Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item. [...]

Comment: I think you may need to separate out these two questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends-
When you talk about magical tinkering, it says this:

> You then touch a Tiny nonmagical object as an action and give it one of the following magical properties of your choice:
>
> - The object sheds bright light in a 5-foot radius and dim light for an additional 5 feet.
> - Whenever tapped by a creature, the object emits a recorded message that can be heard up to 10 feet away. You utter the message when you bestow this property on the object, and the recording can be no more than 6 seconds long.
> - The object continuously emits your choice of an odor or a nonverbal sound (wind, waves, chirping, or the like). The chosen phenomenon is perceivable up to 10 feet away.
> - A static visual effect appears on one of the object’s surfaces. This effect can be a picture, up to 25 words of text, lines and shapes, or a mixture of these elements, as you like.

This ability specifies tiny items, and thus can not target normal weapons, so this is generally a moot point, but even if you have a tiny character with a tiny weapon, it still does not grant any weapon enhancing properties, and as such likely would not count as magical damage.

Now, when you talk about infusing an item, the description says this:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a non-magical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item

Since it says that it turns the item into a magical item, so it deals magical damage

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: “Mute” should be “moot”

Comment: "This ability specifies tiny items, and thus can not target normal weapons" Do you have a source for this? I'm pretty sure that things like daggers would count as Tiny objects.

Comment: I believe it's based on the size of the intended user

Comment: The rules for a light weapon say `A light weapon is small and easy to handle [...]` Small is one size category larger than Tiny so the rules suggest that even the smallest weapon is technically not small enough to be classified as Tiny. It seems like a DM would have to arbitrate in the case of a weapon that is small for a small character. That said, Monks get Ki Empowered Strikes at level 6, so it seems like an Artificer getting a better version of Ki Strikes at the first level is really unbalanced and therefore likely not rules as intended.

Comment: @Rykara: "small" is not the same as "Small"; the latter is a game term, the former is a plain English adjective. I wouldn't try to draw meaningful conclusions about the Size of an object from descriptive text that isn't using the capitalized game terms.